# How backpropagation works in Convolutional Neural Network(CNN)?

Tags: kernel, convolution, backpropagation

I have few question regarding CNN. In the figure below between Layer S2 and C3, 5*5 sized kernel has been used.[image]

Q1. How many kernel has been used there? Do each of these kernel connected with each of the feature map in Layer S2 ?
Q2. When using Max-pooling, while backpropageting error how a max-pooling feature/neuron knows/determines from which (feature map/neuron) in its previous immediate layer it got the max value ?
Q3. If we want to train kernel then we initialize with random value, is there any equation to update these kernel values using backpropagated error value ?
Q4. In the above figure how the backpropagation works between 'Input' and 'C5' layer after getting error from Layer F6 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:**
C1 -> 6 Kernels
C3 -> 16 Kernels

S2 and S4 are just subsampling, this means 2*2 Pixel will be decreased to 1 Pixel
The most populare Pooling Mechanism is the MAX Pooling:

```
 (  5   10 ) -->
 (         ) -->  (10)
 (  7    8 ) -->
```

**Q2:**
You can save the information or if you have enough time re-run the max_pooling and check where the maximum is and then put the error at this position. The other values in this 2*2 Block are zero