# How does a convolution kernel get trained in a CNN?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, convolution, backpropagation

In a CNN, the convolution operation 'convolves' a kernel matrix over an input matrix. Now, I know how a fully connected layer makes use of gradient descent and backpropagation to get trained. But how does the kernel matrix change over time?

There are multiple ways in which the kernel matrix is initialized as mentioned [here, in the Keras documentation](https://keras.io/initializers/). However, I am interested to know how it is trained? If it uses backpropagation too, then is there any paper that describes in detail the training process?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158599/how-backpropagation-works-in-convolutional-neural-networkcnn) also raises a similar question, but it is unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://becominghuman.ai/back-propagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-intuition-and-code-714ef1c38199) you have a well explained post about backpropagation for Convolutional layer. In short, it is also gradient descent just like with FC layer. In fact, you can effectively turn a Convolutional layer into a Fuly Connected layer as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798888/2-d-convolution-as-a-matrix-matrix-multiplication).